# Data Loader for Professional Edition Salesforce That Does Not Use API?

Tags: api, data-loader, professional-edition, salesforceexcelconnector

I am working on a project to clean out old tasks and would like to be able to export all tasks including those which are archived and then upload a list of activity IDs for the ones which I would like to delete.

I would normally use Export All in Dataloader and then mass delete through Dataloader to do this.  Unfortunately this is a Professional Edition of Salesforce which does not have API enabled.

What alternative tool could I use that does not require an API connection and is compatible with Salesforce Professional Edition for mass updating/deleting data like the Dataloader. I have heard the Excel Connector may be an option, but does this require API?

***FYI I am a Mac user as well if this makes a difference***

Comment: if its small amount of data then you can try `dataloader.io`

Comment: dataloader.io would need api access too

Comment: Its 100,000+ records.  And I need something that can be used to delete records, add records, and update records. So I don't think data import wizard would cut it. I basically need dataloader without API access

Answer (score 4):

Depending on just how many records you intend to do at once you can use the [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_import_wizard.htm&type=0) with practically any edition of Salesforce; limited to 50,000 records per run. It is compatible with Safari 5 or later.

Comment: This may be the only option since every other external tools would need api access